# How to pass product metadata to events coming through Stripe customer portal

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe customer portal to let customers manage their billing.  I have added metadata with each products so that I can provision users based on these metadata.

I'm succesfully able to provision users at Stripe Checkout session by passing metadata like this :

```
const session = await Stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: 'subscription',

        metadata: {
           
            teamSize: productObject.metadata.teamSize,
            accountType: productObject.metadata.accountType,
            accountStatus: productObject.metadata.accountStatus
        },

        line_items: [
            {
                price: price_id,
                quantity: 1
            }
        ],

        success_url: `${url}` + "/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'",
        cancel_url: `${url}` + '/cancelled'
    });
```

Similarly, is there any way I can pass product metadata when users comes through stripe customer portal? If not, what would be the best way to get product metadata at different events (invoice updated, customer subscription.updated etc )

```
router.post('/create-customer-portal-session',  async (req, res) => {


    const session = await Stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
        customer: company.billingId,
        return_url: `${url}`
    });

    res.status(200).send(session.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way to pass metadata through on the billing portal call.

If your metadata is stored on the product itself, then you can access it when you handle any subscription webhook events which result from the billing portal session.

1. Pick all product ids from the prices within the [subscription items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-items-data-price)
2. Make a call to [list the product(s)](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/list#list_products-ids) using these ids.
3. Do whatever account provisioning you need to do now that you have product metadata and customer references in your sub.